# Sum of prime numbers less than 2 million

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve a Project Euler problem, it wants me to find the sum of prime numbers below 2 million. Here is the code I wrote :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime (int x)
{
    for(int i = 2; i < x; i++)
    {
        if(x % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main ()
{

    int x = 0;
    for(int i = 3 ; i < 2000000;i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(i))
            x = x + i;
    }


cout<<x+2<<endl;
}
```

I know this is not an efficient way to solve this problem. I found an easier way but I think this solution should give the correct answer too. The answer this code finds is : 1179908154. Can you tell me why this code is giving the wrong answer?

Comment: Look at the sidebar... multiple questions mentioning "two million" and "prime numbers".

Comment: @whitehulk maybe you should start your for loop from i = 2 ?

Comment: Looping to `sqrt(x)` is a much better, and simple option.

Comment: The phrase "all primes less than x" suggests the use of a sieve approach, which will generally be much faster than prime testing each number by division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code gives you the wrong answer since you reach to the point `x`, which is of type `int` cant represent your number.
You can use another data type `unsigned long long` ? which will be able to hold it without overflowing

Comment: @user814064 As noted in a comment on the question, the loop should start at 2, not 3. That bug reduces the answer by 2.